# How To create dynamic data source reader and different file format reader in scala spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to create a program in spark scala that read the data from the different sources based on dynamic based on configuration setting.

i am trying to create a program that read the data in different format like csv,parquet and Sequence files dynamic based on configuration setting.

I tried more please help i am new in scala spark

Answer (score 0):

Please use a config file to specify your input file format and location. For example:

```
import java.io.File
import com.typesafe.config.{ Config, ConfigFactory }

val configFile= System.getProperty("config.file")

val config = ConfigFactory.parseFile(new File(configFile))

val format = config.getString("inputDataFormat")
```

Based on the above `format`, write your conditional statements for reading files.

Comment: what is config.file . is i need to create a file with name ''conf"  and file is the attribute? and where is the location ? is under the resource folder?

Comment: Yes, and you pass it as a an argument `-Dconfig.file="yourConfFile.conf"`